# jQuery drag&drop: cloned draggable moves original

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I've got a problem with Drag & Drop in jQuery. In my code there is a draggable div. When I move it to a certain droppable table cell, a clone of the div is appended to the table cell. But when I drag the clone, the original div is moved instead. This here is the function called on drop:

```
function(event, ui)
{
    var draggable = ui.draggable.clone(true);  // cloning including attrs and children
    draggable.draggable(); // this is something I tried with no effect
    $(this).empty(); // empty the droppable cell
    $(this).append(draggable); // append the div to the cell
}
```

I couldn't find a clear answer by Googling. I don't know if it's got anything to do with this, but the div has a relative position (and needs to stay that way).

How do I make sure the clone can be dragged just like its original?

Comment: Could the `id` attribute be cloned along with the original element? This would most likely cause strange issues.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes it is cloned along with it, but I don't need the id-attribute for the draggable. I use another jquery selector, based on a custom attribute ('[drag=article]').

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I would do it, this should do the trick.

```
 $(".draggable").draggable({ helper: 'clone' });
 $(".droppable").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
       ui.draggable.clone().appendTo($(this)).draggable();
    }
 });
```

I don't know if you did, but do not use id-s on the draggable, cause those are going to be cloned too. Also, you have to append the element before applying the draggable on it.

Comment: Thanks! That works. Maybe the big difference is using appendTo on the clone, instead of using append from the droppable. Would there also be a way to clone the draggable properties to the clone? Because now the new draggable doesn't have a helper and I don't want to hard-code it.

Comment: Found my own answer to that comment: ui.draggable.draggable('option') copies all options of the current draggable.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried passing false into .clone()?  That bool stands for withDataAndEvents, so you're inheriting all the same events that are also attached to the old object.

Edit: if you need withDataAndEvents for other reasons, you can try using draggable("destroy") on the original right before you do the clone, then make it draggable again after?  Not the most elegant but it works: http://jsfiddle.net/GheD5/

Comment: Yes I tried using false in the clone method, but I need the child elements and the attributes to be the same so I have use true. I'll try your edited remark tomorrow, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `draggable` init code to include `helper: "clone"`

```
 $("selector").draggable({
      ...
      helper: "clone",
      ...
 });
```

Otherwise you are dragging the original item which just gets left where you finished up the drag operation.

Comment: Yeah I have that. If I drag the clone, the original gets dragged from its starting position.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Helper Option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-helper)?

Comment: Yes, I used helper: 'clone' but it's not about the dragging but the cloning of the actual element when dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the complete code? I'm just guessing now, but the using 'delegate()' http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ could be the key to your solution.

Comment: I don't see how I should use delegate right now, but I think I already have a solution thanks to rucsi. But thanks.